# Using a python array for calculations

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements

I have a numpy array named distance.

It is actually the distance from the center of a circle divided in equal intervals of 0.1262755.

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.12627551,  0.25255103,  0.37882654,  0.50510206,
    0.63137757,  0.75765309,  0.8839286 ,  1.01020411,  1.13647963,
    1.26275514])
```

I need to use this to find area of the annulus of the circle. The formula is:

```
math.pi*(R**2-r**2)
```

wherein **"R" denotes the large radii** and **"r" the small radii**. Example for area of second annuli is **math.pi(0.25255103^2-0.12627551^2)**

I need to repeat this for the entire distance array and I would like to know how?

Comment: @M4rtini it is math.pi*(R**2-r**2). it is just the mathematical pi

Comment: is that a numpy array?

Comment: @M4rtini yes, it is a numpy array!

Comment: @JayanthKoushik I have just been finding it manually. math.pi*(dist[1:2]**2-dist[0:1]**2) etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([ 0.        ,  0.12627551,  0.25255103,  0.37882654,  0.50510206,
    0.63137757,  0.75765309,  0.8839286 ,  1.01020411,  1.13647963,
    1.26275514])
>>> [math.pi*(R**2-r**2) for R, r in zip(a[1:], a)]
[0.050094279561751477, 0.15028285455350326, 0.25047140574288157, 0.35065999660288272, 0.45084853192401186, 0.55103713865226189, 0.65122565810514155, 0.75141421722864576, 0.85160284775926787, 0.95179134340977567]
```

Comment: This only gives the area of annuli's of the radii next to each other in the list, not all of them. Is that all OP is interested in?

Comment: @M4rtini yes, I wanted the area of each annuli in the circle, and the distance to each annuli is defined by the distance array